# "flutter" fl_chart use future data for AxisTitles

Tags: flutter

I'm working with fl_chart and came across issue on getTitlesWidget in sideTitles.
I'm making graph inside futurebuilder and would like to use fetched data for AxisTitles value. Can anybody teach me how to?

What I would like to acheive is when I make data for AxisTitles(getTitlesWidget: leftTitleWidgets) I would like to use data that I fetch through futurebuilder.
To be specific current value in leftTitleWidgets switch is "case 9000:" but I would like to change it to "followerMin" which are variable made under futurebuilder hasData.

```
Widget leftTitleWidgets(double value, TitleMeta meta) {
  const style = TextStyle(
    color: Color(0xff68737d),
    fontSize: 16.0,
  );
  Widget text;
  switch (value.toInt()) {
    case 9000:
      text = const Text('Min*0.9', style: style);
      break;
    case 11110:
      text = const Text('Max*1.1', style: style);
      break;
    default:
      text = const Text('', style: style);
      break;
  }

  return SideTitleWidget(
    axisSide: meta.axisSide,
    child: text,
  );
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
    children: [
      FutureBuilder(
          future: influData,
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> Snapdata) {
            if (Snapdata.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            } else if (Snapdata.hasError) {
              return const Text('this error');
            } else if (Snapdata.hasData) {
              Map<String, dynamic> data = Snapdata.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
              List<int> followerList = data["Follower"].cast<int>();
              var followerMin = followerList.reduce(min);
              var followerMax = followerList.reduce(max);
              return Center(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 500,
                      height: 500,
                      child: LineChart(LineChartData(
                          titlesData: FlTitlesData(
                            show: true, // タイトルの有無
                            rightTitles: AxisTitles(),
                            topTitles: AxisTitles(),
                            // 下側のタイトル設定
                            bottomTitles: AxisTitles(),
                            leftTitles: AxisTitles(
                              // タイトル名
                              axisNameWidget: const Text(
                                "Follower",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Color(0xff68737d),
                                ),
                              ),
                              axisNameSize: 22.0, //タイトルの表示エリアの幅
                              // サイドタイトルの設定
                              sideTitles: SideTitles(
                                showTitles: true, // サイドタイトルの有無
                                interval: 1.0, // サイドタイトルの表示間隔
                                reservedSize: 40.0, // サイドタイトルの表示エリアの幅
                                getTitlesWidget: leftTitleWidgets, // サイドタイトルの表示内容
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          )),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return Text("");
            }
          })
    ],
  ));
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with add argument?

Comment: thank you for point out vague explanation, I meant adding new argument to leftTitleWidgets function

Comment: it doesn't make much sense to add arguments, since the `getTitlesWidget` gets called within the package. You never call that function yourself. That happens within the package

Comment: thank you for your reply. I'm sorry, I must been not so clear with my situation. I added detail, hope it will clearfy my issue.

Comment: I have problems understanding the problem. I think you maybe misunderstand how the charts work. the `getTitlesWidget` gets triggered automaticaly based on the data you put into the chart. Maybe it's just me but I don't see the problem. Maybe someone else can

Comment: @Ivo my apology for confusion.